# python asyncio.Event.wait() not responding to event.set()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The plan is to have several IO routines running "concurrently" (specifically on a Raspberry Pi, manipulating IO pins and running an SPI interface at the same time). I try to use asyncio to make this happen. However, my simple try-out refuses to run.
This is a reduced version of the code, leaving out the IO pin details:

```
"""\
Reduced problem representation:
this won't run because GPIO details have been left out
"""

import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import asyncio

GPIO_PB = 12         # Define pushbutton channel

async def payload():
    """ Provides some payload sequence using asyncio.sleep() """
    #Payload action
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    #Payload action
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

class IOEvent(asyncio.locks.Event):
    """\
    Create an Event for asyncio, fired by a callback from GPIO
    The callback must take a single parameter: a gpio channel number
    """
    def __init__(self, ioChannel, loop):
        super().__init__(loop = loop)
        self.io = ioChannel

    def get_callback(self):
        "The callback is a closure that knows self when called"
        def callback( ch ):
            print("callback for channel {}".format(ch))
            if ch == self.io and not self.is_set():
                print(repr(self))
                self.set()
                print(repr(self))
        return callback

async def Worker(loop, event):
    print("Entering Worker: {}".format(repr(loop)))
    while loop.is_running():
        print("Worker waiting for {}".format(repr(event)))
        await event.wait()
        print("Worker has event")
        event.clear()
        await payload()
        print("payload ended")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Create an event for the button
pb_event = IOEvent( GPIO_PB, loop)

# register the pushbutton's callback
# Pushing the button calls this callback function
gpio.add_event_callback( GPIO_PB, pb_event.get_callback() )

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(Worker(loop, pb_event))
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.stop()
    loop.close()
```

The output I get is like this:

```
Entering Worker: <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
Worker waiting for <__main__.IOEvent object at 0x76a2a950 [unset]>
callback for channel 12
<__main__.IOEvent object at 0x76a2a950 [unset,waiters:1]>
<__main__.IOEvent object at 0x76a2a950 [set,waiters:1]>
callback for channel 12
```

These lines show the pushbutton repeatedly and correctly firing its callback routine. The first time it calls the `set()` funtion as expected. The event used for the `wait()` call and the `set()` call are the same. But the message *"Worker has event"*, after the `await event.wait()` call never appears.

I looked at [PyQt5 and asyncio: yield from never finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141623/pyqt5-and-asyncio-yield-from-never-finishes?s=1%7C60.2233), but I do not see any other loops than the default loop.

Why does `wait()` never return? How could I find out?

Comment: If callbacks set by `add_event_callback` are called from a different thread (which I suspect is the case, given that they are called without anything having been submitted to the loop), then you can't use `Event.set`, which is not thread-safe. Instead, use `loop.call_later_threadsafe(self.set)`.

Comment: Spot on! Calling self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.set)  does the trick. Thanks.    
I only have to add a local self.guard to prevent mulltiple pushbutton actions to be rembered before  the payload is done: self.is_set() has the same problem :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callbacks set by `add_event_callback` are called from a different thread, as indicated by them being called automatically "in the background". This means that you can't call `set` on an `asyncio.Event` directly from a gpio callback, since asyncio classes are not thread-safe.

To wake up an `asyncio.Event` from a different thread, you can pass `event.set` to `loop.call_soon_threadsafe`. In your case, you would change:

```
self.set()
```

to:

```
self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.set)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I could not find _call_later_threadsafe_. Should this not be _call_soon_threadsafe_?

Comment: THAT `self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.set)` IS AMAZING